# Get IP and Port as const char* in last recvfrom()

Tags: c, winsock, type-conversion

How can you get the last received packets IP address and Port and store it as a `const char*`?

```
const char* strIP = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in*)&RecvAddr)->sin_addr);
const char* strPort = std::to_string(ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in*)&RecvAddr)->sin_port)).c_str();
printf("%s | %s\n", strIP, strPort);
```

The current code being used will print the IP however our Port will be blank so I believe it is an issue converting `USHORT sin_port` to `const char* strPort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const char* strPort = std::to_string(ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in*)&RecvAddr)->sin_port)).c_str();
```

creates a temporary `string`, gets the address of the `string`'s internal buffer and then destroys the `string` because the `string` isn't assigned to anything. That means the pointer returned by `c_str` and referred to by `strPort` is invalid, and using it ventures into undefined behaviour.

It's probably best to just keep the `string` around until you don't need it any more.

```
std::string whatever = std::to_string(ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in*)&RecvAddr)->sin_port));
const char* strPort = whatever.c_str();
```

Or

```
std::string strPort = std::to_string(ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in*)&RecvAddr)->sin_port));
printf("%s | %s\n", strIP, strPort.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need it:

```
short port = ntohs(((struct sockaddr_in*)&RecvAddr)->sin_port);
printf("%s | %d\n", strIP, port);
```